# Save search query result into a model with django

Tags: python, django, search, model, updatemodel

I have the following code in my view. I want to save the query result (if it's true) into another model. How to achieve this?

```
def scan(request):
    print(request.session)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        srch = request.POST['srh']

        if srch:
            match = ReportModel.objects.filter(Q(serialNumber__iexact=srch))
            if match:
                return render(request, 'admin/scan.html', {'sr': match})
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'No result yet for the requested device!')
        else:
            return redirect('/scan/')

    return render(request, 'admin/scan.html')
```

Comment: how is declared the `another model`?

Comment: the same fields with the model being queried

Comment: I have 2 models of the same fields, one for lost and the other for found.so I want to save the result of the search query (if true) to the found model.

Answer (score -1):

There is one way. You can create your own cache.

The logic is these steps:

1. Let's suppose there is `A` and `B` model.
2. Define `search_result` field as `None` in `B` model.
3. When you make query(search) through `A` model just check `B.search_result` value, if it is `None` change `search_result` value to query result(Be sure that your query is executed) and return it. If it is not `None` return value(`B.search_result`).
4. When there is manipulation(insert, delete, update) on your model `A` change `B.search_result` to None.

It is the simple caching your data. And when you use `all()`, `filter(**kwargs)` methods in queryset it does not execute query, so wrap it into list or dumpt it into `json`, so than change value of `B.search_result`.

Comment: Thanks,but note that my search result returns all the fields associated to the filter criteria.in this case should define all the fields as none?

Comment: No, you should just do `B.search_result = None`, when you search and result is true you will just do `B.search_result = {'field_of_a_1': value1,'field_of_a_2': value2, ...}` and it is enough.

Comment: This is not a good answer. The question asks how you can save a query into a model. That is quite a different thing from caching - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/.